# Вертикальный текст

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать эту часть верстки, чтобы текст был вертикально. Без переносов в одну строку, по центру. Я учусь верстать, и не могу понять как эту часть сделать [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Думаю поможет css-свойство transform: rotate(-90deg)

Comment: если не получиться самому, то вставьте свой html и css сюда

Answer (score 1):

Например можно transform применить.

```css
#blok{
    width: 50px;
    height: 150px;
;
}
#blok p{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="blok">
    <p>Переворачиваемый текст</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У стиля [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) есть такой параметр. Прочитайте о нём, там их несколько

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  background: gray;
}

.vertical-text {
  writing-mode: sideways-lr;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="vertical-text">Вертикальный текст</div>
</div>
```

---

Так же есть вариант реализовать это при помощи `transform: rotate`, но придётся поизвращаться над конечным результатом

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 200px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical-text {
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="vertical-text">Вертикальный текст</div>
</div>
```